# I cant migrate a laravel project

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, laravel-8

Im having problems opening a laravel project because I cannot do a php artisan migrate. It shows the following error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'techdb.settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select `key`, `value` from `settings`)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel-pos\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 671|             throw new QueryException(
672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
673|             );
674|         }
675|

    • A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

  1   [internal]:0
  Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel-pos\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:331
  PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'techdb.settings' doesn't exist")
  PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel-pos>
```

I already created a database in mysql and updated the env but it wont migrate. What was it referring when it said in the error, 'techdb.settings' doesnt exist?

I also found this at the providers folder. It could be the problem?

```
       <?php

       namespace App\Providers;

       use App\Models\Setting;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    // 'key' => 'value'
    $settings = Setting::all('key', 'value')
        ->keyBy('key')
        ->transform(function ($setting) {
            return $setting->value;
        })
        ->toArray();
    config([
       'settings' => $settings
    ]);

    config(['app.name' => config('settings.app_name')]);
}
```

}

Comment: try it  `php artisan migrate:fresh`..

Comment: Check your logs for the full stack trace. This gives you an idea of where the reference to `techdb.settings` is made. Could be that there is code in a service provider which needs the table. In that case, comment out that code, than migrate, than uncomment again. And than rewrite the code such that you or anyone else ever his this issue again.

Comment: Im sorry but im new to laravel so im not sure where can i see that "logs" to see the full stack trace. If you dont mind, can you teach me step by step?

Comment: The log at app/storage/log

Comment: Anyway, do you already check your database which's contain this table?

Comment: do you mean the database from phpmyadmin? its a new database i created so it doesnt have tables yet.

Comment: Helloo ive found the provider and i commented it. it works!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a solution that every time you fresh the database and you have to comment on it out or your teammates who want to install the project on his system he doesn't know what you did and where did. So it can be messy..So, here when you are going to migrate, the boot method search for a settings table that is not present in your database that's why it throws an error. So what you can do, you can bind it an try-catch like follow.

```
try {
            $settings = Setting::all('key', 'value')
        ->keyBy('key')
        ->transform(function ($setting) {
            return $setting->value;
        })
        ->toArray();
    config([
       'settings' => $settings
    ]);

    config(['app.name' => config('settings.app_name')]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
           
            return false;
        }
```